# style search bars in material table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Hello Every body i'm using material table but i'm facing a styling issue which is the search fields not aligned like here
[Layout view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUFbl.png)

and i don't know how to do it, 
Any Clues ? Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You need to share some code or a codesandbox to reproduce this problem pls.

Comment: @Domino987 i didn't do anything except that i installed and import it no styles and no more code from my side

Answer (score 0):

there is a prop for styling search box that we can pass in options props like below in given code block

```
<MaterialTable                                                                     
   options={{
      emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,
      searchFieldStyle: {
         padding: "5px 10px 5px 15px",
         borderRadius: "9px",
         fontWeight: 450,
         disableUnderline: true,
         border: "1px solid #707070",
       }
   }}
/>
```